Finite equinumerosity and FOL
Suppose $F$ and $G$ are distinct unary predicates in some first-order language $L$ which includes $=$ and may include some other predicates. Can one prove that there is no $L$-sentence $\phi$ such that $\phi$ is true in a finite model $(M,I)$ iff $|F^I|=|G^I|$? I am pretty sure one can, but I can't figure out how.

Yes, this is true. First use compactness to prove it for the empty (= equality-only) language, and then extend that to general languages by interpreting the non-equality symbols "stupidly" (e.g. all relations are the empty relation, all functions are projection onto first coordinate, and all constant symbols - if any - point to the same thing). I'm commenting rather than answer since I think this has been asked before here.

I feel dense today, but I don't see how to use compactness to prove this for the empty language.

To say a little more, given the restriction to finite models, I have a hard time seeing how compactness would be helpful. I think that if one drops the finiteness restriction on the models, one can show the result by using the method of proof of upward Lowenheim-Skolem (and it doesn't need Choice, I think).

A rather non-elementary proof is that monadic FOL is decidable but FOL + finite counting is not decidable.
But here's an elementary proof.
Say that objects $\alpha$ and $\beta$ in a model $(M,I)$ are indiscernible with respect to a set $P$ of predicates provided that $(\gamma_1,...,\gamma_{k-1},\alpha,\gamma_{k+1},...,\gamma_{n}) \in Q^I$ iff $(\gamma_1,...,\gamma_{k-1},\alpha,\gamma_{k+1},...,\gamma_{n}) \in Q^I$ for all $Q$ in $P$ and all $\gamma_i$ in $M$.
Lemma: Let $\phi$ be a sentence in prenex form with $n$ quantifiers. Let $(M,I)$ be a
model with a set $B$ of at least $n$ objects that do not have a name in $\phi$ and that are are
indiscernible with respect to all predicates in $\phi$. Let $(M_A,I_A)$ be a model agrees with $(M,I)$ for the objects in $M$ but adds some
set $A$ of new objects unnamed by names in $\phi$ that are indiscernible from the members of $B$ with respect to
all predicates in $\phi$. Then $\phi$ is true in $(M_A,I_A)$.
Proof: Proceed by induction on $n$. Obvious for $n=0$. Suppose true for $n-1$ quantifiers
and $\phi$ has $n$ quantifiers. If $\phi$ is $\exists x \psi(x)$, then add a new name $a$
to the language, extend the interpretation $I$ to $I'$ such that putting $I'(a)$ for $x$
satisfies $\phi(x)$. Then, $\psi(a)$ has $n-1$ quantifiers, and applying the $n-1$ case
with $B\backslash \{ I'(a) \}$ in place of $B$ and $I'$ in place of $I$ completes the proof.
Now suppose $\phi$ is $\forall x \psi(x)$. Suppose $a$ is a new name, and suppose $I'$
extends $I$ to assign a denotation for $a$. Then $\psi(a)$ is true in $(M,I')$. Again, we have $n-1$
quantifiers, and we have named at most one indiscernible from $B$, so $\psi(a)$ will be true in
$(M_A,I'_A)$. Thus, $\psi(x)$ is satisfied in $(M_A,I_A)$ when we put for $x$ any object $\alpha$
in $M$. It remains to show that it will be satisfied when we put for $x$ any object $\alpha$ not in $A$. Fix $\beta\in B$. Since $\alpha$ and $\beta$ are unnamed by $\psi(x)$ and indiscernible with respect to the predicates in $\psi(x)$, given that $\beta$ satisfies $\psi(x)$ for $x$, so
does $\alpha$. $\Box$
Now, suppose we have $\phi$ as in the question. Choosing trivial interpretations for all predicates
in $\phi$ other than $=$, $F$ and $G$ (thanks to Noah Schweber for this hint), assume without loss of generality that $F$ and $G$ are the
only predicates other than $=$ in $\phi$. Suppose $\phi$ has $n$ quantifiers and $m$ names and let
$(M,I)$ be a model such that $|F^I|\ge m+n$ and $G^I$ is disjoint from $F^I$. Then there will be at
least $n$ $\phi$-unnamed objects in $F^I$, and all objects in $F^I$ will be indiscernible with respect to the predicates in $\phi$. If $B$ is the set of all $\phi$-unnamed
objects in $F^I$, and $A$ is a set of new indiscernibles for the members of $B$, then $\phi$ is true in $(M_A,I_A)$, but $|F^{I_A}| = |A|+|G^{I_A}|$.
